# how to show only one time data using foreach loop in laravel....please code

Tags: php, laravel

This is my display code

```
 @foreach($managefee as $managefees)
    @if($managefees->university==$university[0]->id)
        @if($managefees->eduId=="Undergraduate")

           @foreach($dept as $depts)
             @if($depts->id==$managefees->deptId)
                  <h4>{{$depts->name}}</h4>

                @foreach($degree as $degrees)
                    @if($degrees->id==$managefees->degreeId)
                       <li>{{$degrees->name}}</li>
                    @endif
                  @endforeach

             @endif
             @endforeach

        @endif

    @endif
@endforeach
```

Expected output:

[image: expected output picture]

In this Computer Science and Engineering are the main Category and other are sub categories...I want to display only one time category and remaining subcategories should behind according to Category....but categories are repeating again and again when subcategory added....I want to show only one time category display all the time....

Here is my Database Table:

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+---------------+-----+------------+
| id |  fee   | deptId | degreeId | university | hec_dept |          degreeR           | hec |     eduId     | pec | deleted_at |
+----+--------+--------+----------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+---------------+-----+------------+
|  1 | 250000 |      1 |        6 |          1 |        1 | lorem ipsum dolor sit      | HEC | Undergraguate | PEC | null       |
|  2 | 230000 |      1 |        7 |          1 |        1 | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet | HEC | Undergraguate | PEC | null       |
+----+--------+--------+----------+------------+----------+----------------------------+-----+---------------+-----+------------+
```

Here is my controller query:

```
public function findUniversityDetailByCity($id) {
    $uniid = Crypt::decrypt($id);
    $heading = $uniid;
    $university = manageUniversityModel::where('id', '=', $uniid)->get();
    $city = addcity::all();
    $managefee = managefee::all();
    $degree = manageDegreeModel::all();
    $dept = uniFormDepartment::all();
    $country = addCountry::all();
    $edulevel = edulevel::all();
    return view('findUniversityDetailByCity', compact('university', 'city', 'managefee', 'degree', 'dept', 'country', 'edulevel'));
}
```

Comment: show your controller query ?

Comment: I would create a realtionships where dept has many degrees, that way depts will contain your degrees and wil be shown only once for each degree

Comment: here is my controler query

Comment: @Ali plz edit your question post your controller function clearly

Comment: @ Hamelraj  plz see the picture....here is my controller query...in question post

Comment: i am waiting for your answer  @ Hamelraj

Comment: how do you use your migration? can I see the structure of your category and sub category migration?

Answer (score 0):

**manageUniversityModel.php**

```
// this is how you create relationship between university and managefee or whatever...
public function managefees() {
    return $this->hasMany(managefee::class, 'university', 'id');
}
```

**managefee.php**

```
public function departments() {
    return $this->hasMany(uniFormDepartment::class, 'deptId', 'id');
}

public function degrees() {
    return $this->hasMany(manageDegreeModel::class, 'degreeId', 'id');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function findUniversityDetailByCity($id) {
    // I don't know why would you use Crypt here?
    $uniid = Crypt::decrypt($id);
    $heading = $uniid;

    // you can use find(), this will fetch first model by id
    $university = manageUniversityModel::find($uniid);

    // instead of fetch every single row from the database, use where cluse
    // and using with() allows you to load related models. 
    $managefees = managefee::with('departments', 'degrees')
                            ->where('university', $uniid)
                            ->where('eduId', 'Undergraduate')->get();

    // You don't need to fetch them separately, let Laravel do it for you.
    // $degree = manageDegreeModel::all(); <-- this is already loaded in managefees 
    // $dept = uniFormDepartment::all();   <-- this is already loaded in managefees 


    // I would not recommend fetching every row at the same, instead use limits and pagination.
    $city = addcity::all();
    $country = addCountry::all();
    $edulevel = edulevel::all();

    return view('findUniversityDetailByCity', compact('university', 'city', 'managefees', 'country', 'edulevel'));
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($managefees as $managefee)
    // you don't need to check for ids manually 
    @foreach($managefee->departments as $department)
         <h4>{{ $department->name }}</h4>

         // do this only if you have same degrees in every department
         @foreach($managefee->degrees as $degree)
             <li>{{ $degree->name }}</li>
         @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**PS**: Learn to use database relationships and joins. You could have made better database structure.